# Format right aligned number with a preceding dollar sign

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, format

I try to create a simple function, that returns a right aligned number with a preceding dollar sign.

Expected output:

```
$1000
  $10
 $100
```

My current code is:

```
def aligned_num(num):
    print('${0:4}'.format(num))
```

But this gives:

```
$1000
$  10
$ 100
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put a format string inside a format string.

```py
l = [1000, 10, 100]

for n in l:
    # 3.6 and newer:
    print(f"Money earned: {f'${n}':>5}.")

for n in l:
    # older than 3.6:
    print("Money earned: {0:>5}.".format("${0}".format(n)))
```

Outcome:

```
Money earned: $1000.
Money earned:   $10.
Money earned:  $100.

Money earned: $1000.
Money earned:   $10.
Money earned:  $100.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work this way:

```
def aligned_num(num):
    str_num = '$'+str(num)
    print('{0:>5}'.format(str_num))
```

Is there a way, without changing the integer to a string?